# Scrape information within <a href and <span

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would need to scrape journalists' names and journals from this website:

https://www.politicasufacebook.it/giornalisti/

What I am looking for is to get specifically `<a href` information (journalist's name) and `< span` (newspaper's name).

For example, *Andrea Scanzi*:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/andreascanzi74/" style="color:#003060" target="_blank">Andrea Scanzi</a>
```

and *Il Fatto Quotidiano*

```
<span style="font-size:13px;line-height:25px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Il Fatto Quotidiano</span>
```

I have wrote the following

```
with requests.Session() as s: # use session object for efficiency of tcp re-use
    s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    r = s.get('https://www.politicasufacebook.it/giornalisti/')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
```

but I do not know how to continue in order to extract such information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `soup.find_all` with the desired tag and attributes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.politicasufacebook.it/giornalisti/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

journalists = soup.find_all('a', {'style': 'color:#003060', 'target': '_blank'})
newspapers = soup.find_all('span', {'style': 'font-size:13px;line-height:25px'})

for i, v in enumerate(journalists):
    print(v.text.strip() + ' - ' + newspapers[i].text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Roberto Saviano - La Repubblica
Marco Travaglio - Il Fatto Quotidiano
Enrico Mentana - La7
Andrea Scanzi - Il Fatto Quotidiano
Massimo Gramellini - Corriere Della Sera
Nicola Porro - Rete 4
Salvo Sottile - Rai1
Carmelo Abbate - Storie Nere
Gad Lerner - autonomo
Michele Serra - La Repubblica
...
```